# Why does this sum return unevaluated when testing for convergence?

Tags: summation

Why does *Mathematica* return unevaluated for `SumConvergence[Sin[\[Pi]/n^2], n]`? I tried looking at the documentation, but I can't find any possible issues. The series is pretty easy to prove that it converges manually, thus I am wondering why Mathematica is not able to do it. Any insight, or workaround?

I am using *Mathematica 11.3* on Windows x64.

---

I also confirmed with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+sin(pi%2Fn%5E2)+from+n%3D1+to+infinity) that the series converges

Comment: `NSum[Sin[π/n^2], {n, 1, Infinity}, VerifyConvergence -> True]` evaluates to a value which appears to indicate that Mathematica is able to verify the convergence. `WolframAlpha` states `{The root test is inconclusive., By the comparison test, the series converges.}` However, while one of the `Method's specified for `SumConvergence` is `"RootTest"` (function returns unevaluated), there is no `Method` specified for `SumConvergence` corresponding to `ComparisonTest`

Comment: @BobHanlon how does wolfram alpha implement the comparison test?

Comment: Sounds like a question for someone at WolframAlpha